# Data movement of wrong files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I wrote a function to move files from a folder to another folder. it works but the issue that when opening the destination folder I see my google script and some other documents that aren't in the source folder.

here is the code

```
function moveFiles() {
var currentMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+6", "MMMM");
const source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX');
const files = source_folder.getFiles();
const dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXX').createFolder(currentMonth + " test text");
while (files.hasNext()) {
const file = files.next();
dest_folder.addFile(file);
source_folder.removeFile(file);
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to move the files to the created folder using Google Apps Script.
- From the following situation,

  > it works but the issue that when opening the destination folder I see my google script and some other documents that aren't in the source folder.

  - I though that you might want to move the files of specific mimeType to the folder.
- In the current stage, I think that `moveTo(destination)` of Class File can be used for moving the files to the folder.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, the files are retrieved using `getFilesByType`.

```
function moveFiles() {
  var currentMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+6", "MMMM");
  const source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX');
  const files = source_folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  const dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX').createFolder(currentMonth + " test text");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().moveTo(dest_folder);
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, Google Spreadsheet files are moved.
- When you want to modify the mimeType, please modify `MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS` for your situation.

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the files are retrieved using `getFiles` and the mimeTypes are checked in the loop.

```
function moveFiles() {
  var currentMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+6", "MMMM");
  const source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX');
  const files = source_folder.getFiles();
  const dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXX').createFolder(currentMonth + " test text");
  const exclusiveMimeTypes = [MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT, MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    if (!exclusiveMimeTypes.includes(file.getMimeType())) {
      file.moveTo(dest_folder);
    }
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, from `when opening the destination folder I see my google script and some other documents that aren't in the source folder`, the files except for the Google Apps Script files and Google Document files are moved.
- If you want to add more exclusive mimeTypes, please modify above script.

#### References:

- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype)
- [moveTo(destination) of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)
- [Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)